# Using multiple annotation checks in java (Logical OR operations)

Tags: java, annotations

I have two annotation checks in Java @IsSystemController @HasRole(role:Administrator) I need to give permission if One of those two is true

```
     @PUT
     @Path("/{component}/{roleName}")
     @HasRole(role=Administrator)
     @IsSystemController
     public IdOnlyResponse updateController(String A,String b,String c){

     }
```

I need to do a get a response if one the condition is true how to do this?